# Excel 14 instead of Excel 15 (2013) launched

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I make a simple C# project with a reference to Excel 15

```
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
```

However, Excel 14 (2010) is launched when I run the program

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var v = a.Version; //14 !!
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Which version(s) of Excel are installed on the computer?

Comment: both versions 2010 and 2013

Comment: As best I can tell this has nothing to do with [tag:vba]?

Comment: oh the endless joys of global state and registry. 20 years later, it never gets old !

Comment: Having two versions of Office installed on one machine voids the warranty.  Something the installer strongly warns against btw.  There can only be one that's automatable.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a hard time thinking that in the general dotnet framework there is a special casing rule that check the office warranty. my code access a property only available in excel 15 (workbook.modeltables) and was running 1 day ago.. so something, somewhere must have changed...

Comment: I have seen this done, starting an old version of an automatable program would get it to modify the registry to make the old version the "current" one.  That was in the days before UAC however, no idea if Office is capable of such a feat today.  Try starting Excel 2013 manually, preferably from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: thank you for the tip, which gives me an idea of the kind of pb I might have if I pursue with 2 versions. I will make sure that my users have 2013 installed only.